# How to forcefully log out a user when user closes tab or browser on website built on django2.0

Tags: django, authentication, django-authentication

I used built-in login logout functionality by Django  using Django authentication,
this is the following url pattern for logging in
urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.home),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/', include('users.urls')),
    path('users/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('dashboard/', include('dashboard.urls')),

]
```

And i added following in my setting.py
settings.py:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'dashboard:home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'dashboard:home'
```

Now how do I check whether user closed his browser and he should be logged out? 
PS:I made my own logging in and sign-up HTML pages and made my own customuser derived from AbstractUser

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just set the [`SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE) setting to true, so that Django's session cookies are only valid for the [length of the browser session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/#browser-length-sessions-vs-persistent-sessions).

> If `SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE` is set to True, Django will use browser-length cookies – cookies that expire as soon as the user closes their browser. Use this if you want people to have to log in every time they open a browser.

Answer (score 3):

You can listen for the window or tab close event like this.  This approach needs jQuery and JavaScript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){         
    $(window).on("beforeunload", function(e) {
        $.ajax({
                url: logout_url,
                method: 'GET',
            })
    });
});
```

Comment: Where do I add this code? I have never seen such code before. Where can  i learn more about this?

Comment: Okay, this needs to be on every html page. usually we have base.html and every page is extended from base.html page. So putting it on one place does the job.

Answer (score 1):

To logout the session whenever you close the browser

you need to input the following lines in your **setting.py**

## auto logout when user close the browser

```
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True
```